# How can I edit the grid position of a QtElement in the QtDesigner without manipulating the .ui file manually?

Tags: qt, qt-designer

How can I change the grid position of the labels "Bottom left" and "bottom right" within the QTDesigner?

In this case, I would like edit the column number of "Bottom left" (from 1 to 0) and "bottom right" (from 0 to 1) without changing the XML manually, as shown in the snippet from the *.ui file.

[image]

If I'm using drag and drop, I'am facing some issues with additional columns or rows and in the end, I have to change the *.ui file manually again.

```xml
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="top_left">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Top left</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="1">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="top_right">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Top right</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="bottom_right">
        <property name="text">
         <string>bottom right</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="1">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="bottom_left">
        <property name="text">
         <string>bottom left</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
  </widget>
```

Comment: Can't you just change the objects' names in QtDesigner?

Comment: @NgocMinhNguyen Yes, sure. I could also copy/ paste all the necessary stuff from one element to another but I thought, someone knows a better way. This is only a simple example but if it's more complex, I guess it will be more complicated and cumbersome

Comment: In that case, yeah, I would like to know too :D.